# Proving a code fragment correct under partial correctness

Tags: logic

I'm asked to prove the correctness of the following annotated program:

$\{ \text{true} \}$

```
if (x < y)      m = x - y;
else if (x = y) m = x + y;
else            m = x * y;
```

$\{ ((x<y) \land m=x-y) \lor ((x=y)\land m=x+y) \lor ((x>y)\land m=x*y) \}$

using the if-else inference rule.

The problem is, I don't really get what that inference rule says. Or in other words, I get the inference rule but it seems to be useless:

$$\{P\land B\}C_1\{Q\},\{P\land \lnot B\}C_2\{Q\}$$

---

$$\{P\} \text{ if}(B) C_1 \text{ else }C_2 \{Q\}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction:**

Rule 
$$ \frac{
\{P\land B\}\ C\ \{Q\},\quad\{P\land \lnot B\}\ D\ \{Q\}
}{
\{P\}\ \mathtt{if(}B\mathtt{)}\ C\ \mathtt{else}\ D\ \{Q\}
} \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$

tells us that given that $\{P\land B\}\ C\ \{Q\}$ and $\{P\land \lnot B\}\ D\ \{Q\}$ are true, we can conclude that $\{P\}\ \mathtt{if(}B\mathtt{)}\ C\ \mathtt{else}\ D\ \{Q\}$ is true.

**Example:**

Consider the following code:

```
 {true}
 if (x < 0) y = -x;
 else y = x;
 {y = |x|}
```

If we want to prove it, we need to fit it into `{P} if(B) C else D {Q}` rule (because it is the only one that contains `if`), so we know that `{P} = {true}`, `{B} = {x < 0}`, and `{Q} = {y = |x|}`. To use $(\spadesuit)$ we should first make sure that `{P ∧ B } C {Q}` and `{P ∧ ¬B} D {Q}` hold. However,
`{x < 0} y = -x {y = |x|}` and `{x ≥ 0} y = x {y = |x|}` are both true by the rule of assignment (and some simplification), hence, the premise of $(\spadesuit)$ is satisfied and we can conclude that our code is correct.

Can you extend this example to your code?

Comment: I kinda don't get where the assignment inference rule gets in all this. The way I used it, I worked from the postcondition and applied the replacement in the inference rule until I get to the precondition. The if statement gets in the way...

Comment: @user54609 It would be something along the lines of `{x < 0} {x < 0, -x = -x} y = -x {x < 0, y = -x} {x < 0, y = |x|} {y = |x|}`, I don't know exactly what kind of an assignment rule you use. Sequential braces `{} {} {}` denote just logical inference and are not a part of Hoare logic.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the $P$ we need is "true", the $Q$ we need is the long statement at the end of the code, the condition $B$ is $x<y$, statement $C_1$ is `m= x - y` and $C_2$ is itself an if-then construct, namely `if (x = y) m = x + y; else m = x * y;`. So to apply the inference rule you need the two premises as mentioned. The first is just 
$$ \{\text{true}\land x<y\}\text{m = x - y}\{ ((x<y) \land m=x-y) \lor ((x=y)\land m=x+y) \lor ((x>y)\land m=x*y) \}$$
and should not be hard. For the second, you need to deal with the remeining if-then in a similar way.